# Waterline Update Through Association

Tags: javascript, many-to-many, sails.js, waterline

I have a through association for two objects, `Assignment` and `Tags`. They are joined through the model `AssignmentTag`. I am able to read & write between these objects fine, but when I try to update, it doesn't drop the existing associations prior [see notes for .update()](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/update#?notes).

I believe I should be able to pass an array of Tag IDs to the Assignment model and it drop the current associations and update the new associations.

```
    Assignment.update({id: req.param("assignmentId")}, {tags: tags})
                .exec(function (err, updated) {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.serverError(err);
                    }

                    return res.json({
                        updated
                    }
                });
```

`Assignment.js` model is:

```
    module.exports = {
        connection: db_connection,
        tableName: 'assignments',
        attributes: {
            id: {
                type: 'integer',
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                unique: true
            },
            title: {
                type: 'string'
            }, // varchar(255)
            description: {
                type: 'text'
            }, // text
            // an assignment may have many tags
            tags: {
                collection: 'tag',
                via: 'assignment',
                through: 'assignmenttag'
            },
        }
    };
```

`Tag.js` model is:

```
    module.exports = {
        connection: db_connection,
        tableName: 'tags',
        attributes: {
            id: {
                type: 'integer',
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                unique: true
            },
            title: {
                type: 'string'
            }, // varchar(255)
            description: {
                type: 'text'
            }, // text
            // A tag may have many assignments
            assignments: {
                collection: 'assignment',
                via: 'tag',
                through: 'assignmenttag'
            },
        }
    };
```

`AssignmentTag.js` model is:

```
    module.exports = {
        connection: db_conection,
        tableName: 'assignment_tag',
        attributes: {
            id: {
                type: 'integer',
                primaryKey: true,
                autoIncrement: true,
                unique: true
            },
            assignment: {
                columnName: 'assignment_id',
                model: 'assignment'
            },
            tag: {
                columnName: 'tag_id',
                model: 'tag'
            },
        }
    };
```

Any idea why tag associations aren't dropping on `.update()`?

---

UPDATE: I have created an Issue on the Waterline project to get some further help. I have isolated the issue in a Repository that is linked on the Waterline issue. https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1453

---

RESOLVED: Waterline was responsive after about a week and updated the model associations to accommodate this request. See issue: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1453. They apparently are re-writing these associations in an upcoming release so this issue should be obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved via the following issue posted on the Waterline repo: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1453.

Comment: Hello, please add some detail to your answer so that it would be clear and easier to understand.

Comment: Look at the attached issue with Waterline. It is all explained in that dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the info. While providing links to external resources is helpful, it is better to provide the solution in the answer itself, and use the hyperlinks for reference. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for tips on how to write good answers.